# What is the Name of this Toggling Puzzle?

Tags: logical-deduction, puzzle-identification

I came across an interesting toggling puzzle while looking through a code repository on GitHub. I want to find out more about it and see if there is any info on how to solve it, how to ensure solvability etc., but I can't seem to find any references to it online. The closest I can find is a puzzle called "lights out" which is in a grid and always has adjacent lights toggled when toggling a particular light. Is the puzzle I found one that is already well known but which I just don't know the name for so I can search for it, or is it a one-off wonder?

The rules are simple - toggle switches so they all end up as `O`, but be aware that pairs of switches are connected. There is a version where the connections are hidden so you have to work the connections out yourself - this could be interesting if the goal is to minimize the number of goes.

```
            ┌─────────┐
          ┌─│─────┐   │
        ┌─│─│─┐   │   │
      ┌─│─│─│─│─┐ │   │
    ┌─│─│─│─│─│─│─│─┐ │
    │ │ │ │ │ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
    X X X X X X X X X X
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ │ │ │ │ │
    │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │
    │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │
    │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │
    │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │
    │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │
    │ │ └─│─│─┘ │ │ │ │
    └─│───│─│───┘ │ │ │
      │   │ └─────┘ │ │
      │   └─────────┘ │
      └───────────────┘

Switch to toggle (0─9, or QUIT):
```

Comment: Can you share the GitHub repo where you found the puzzle?

Comment: I don't think I get the full logic behind this puzzle. 0-4 are linked to 5-9, so all you have to do is toggle either 0-4 or 5-9 and all the items will be O. Like if I toggle switch 0, both 0 and it's pair (8) becomes O. Repeat for 1-4 and all 10 will be O. Or is it in both directions so if you toggle 0 it will change 6 and 8?

Comment: I think that configuration just happened to be simple to solve. The connections are generated randomly by the code.

Comment: @Bubbler https://github.com/asweigart/PythonStdioGames

Comment: @RobinAndrews So many games there. What is the title of this particular game?

Comment: https://github.com/asweigart/PythonStdioGames/blob/main/inprogress/switchboard.py amd https://github.com/asweigart/PythonStdioGames/blob/main/inprogress/switchboard2.py

Comment: Looks like the creator calls it Switchboard, but could be his creation. Also, I played several rounds with the links randomized and it was always the same. Choose the 5 numbers with arrows under them, or the 5 numbers with arrows above them. Enter either set of 5 numbers without ever entering a number from the other set and you win.

Comment: Can you see a way to make the puzzle intriguing? Maybe random connections but check the puzzle is solvable and try a new config if not?

Comment: @RobinAndrews I'm thinking maybe some variation where one switch has multiple links, or maybe switches go to different depths (i.e. 0 goes to depth 2, so you toggle 0 it also toggles it's pair and it's pair's pair) I do actually find it quite interesting in theory, so I'm going to be playing around with it a bit